# How to add jquery library to an html file?

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to include the library in my local system. please do correct me if i'm wrong here.
Thanks in advance to those who likes to reply.

```
<script src="C:\xampp\htdocs\Firstpage\jquery-2.0.3.min" type="text/javascript">
```

Comment: You should show sample code of what you've already attempted so we can help guide you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the thing is, a ".js" is missing

second thing is, if you ever want to publish your first page you should either use an online source like Miind Anantwar postet or you should not total path

use path from the there were your files are located

e.g

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\Firstpage\index.html
```

may you have a folder in there like

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\Firstpage\js\jquery.js
```

than you can include them in your firstpage.html like

```
 <script src="./js/jquery.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 4):

**Adding jQuery to Your Web Pages**

The jQuery library is a single JavaScript file, and you reference it with the HTML  tag (notice that the  tag should be inside the  section):

Add bellow lines to your header section

```
<head>
<script src="/path/to/your/js/file/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

OR use GOOGLE CDN (In here you don't need this)

```
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js">
</script>
</head>
```

Comment: Note that none of this will load the version of jQuery the poster is trying to use.

Comment: yes.So please download the latest version of JQUERY everytime when you need it

Comment: Sorry, let me rephrase that: it would be helpful if you'd edit the answer to include the version the OP was asking about. Don't assume the fix is obvious to the OP - if it were, the question wouldn't have been asked.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script src="/Firstpage/jquery-2.0.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

You are confusing file system paths with URL paths. The above will work with your current XAMPP setup.

Answer (score 0):

Do this.

```
<head>
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

and don't forget to make your calls when document is ready.

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    console.log('ready!');  
});
```

And put Jquery before all other scripts.